# Matlab. Can't merge double arrays into RGB image

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, rgb, data-conversion

I have a color, rgb image in Matlab (m,n,3)[double]. I perform a linear diffusion process on each channel separately. The first element in the output of LinearDiffusion is a double array (m,n,1).

```
[m,n,j]=size(noisy_image)
rgb_im=zeros(m,n,3);
for chn=1:3        
    noisy_chn=noisy_image(:,:,chn);    
    [rgb_im(:,:,chn), diff_un]=LinearDiffusion2016(noisy_chn, 0, dt, maxnl);
end
```

I would like to display rgb_im, which is (m,n,3)[double]. But no matter what I do, always get a blank square, eventhough image values are not saturated. I have no issues with grayscale(uint8) images. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** source image is (m,n,3)[unit8], but I turn each channel into double to feed it to LinearDiffusion.

Thank you.

Comment: Getting a blank square means that when you plot it using `imshow` looks white? If your image is double it must be normalized to [0..1]. Try using `imshow(yourimage,[])` and you should see the image correctly.

Comment: rgb_im was uint, actually. It was me tinkering with the image who turned it into double to feed it to LinearDiffusion. My fault, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that MATLAB interprets floating point numbers in images as a fraction between 0 and 1 (inclusive), while integers are interpreted as bit values between 0 and 255 (inclusive). You've converted your integer values into doubles, done your math on them, and then directly piped them back into `imshow`. MATLAB sees that they are doubles and clamps all the values greater than 1 at 1, and so all you see is white unless you happened to have some purely black pixels. You have two options: convert back to integer as you have done in your self-answer, or else divide by 255 to rescale the values.

It would be helpful if this information was given in the `imshow` help file, but you have to dig down to the low-level [CData](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html#prop_CData) image property to get this information:

> Image color data, specified in one of these forms:
>
> - 3-D array of RGB triplets — This format defines true color image data using RGB triplet values. Each RGB triplet defines a color for one pixel of the image. An RGB triplet is a three-element vector that specifies the intensities of the red, green, and blue components of the color. The first page of the 3-D array contains the red components, the second page contains the green components, and the third page contains the blue components. Since the image uses true colors instead of colormap colors, the CDataMapping property has no effect.
>
>   - If CData is of type double, then an RGB triplet value of [0 0 0] corresponds to black and [1 1 1] corresponds to white.
>   - If CData is an integer type, then the image uses the full range of data to determine the color. For example, if CData is of type uint8, then [0 0 0] corresponds to black and [255 255 255] corresponds to white. If CData is of type int8, then [-128 -128 -128] corresponds to black and [127 127 127] corresponds to white.
>   - If CData is of type logical, then [0 0 0] corresponds to black and [1 1 1] corresponds to white.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that each channel of a rgb image has to be uint8 (not double!!). This line did the trick:

```
imshow(uint8(rgb_im));
```

Regards